# Best development workflow when using git submodules?

Tags: git, service, git-submodules

I have a project that has a couple git submodules for services. E.G.

.

+--docker-compose.yml

+--playbooks

+--service1Submodule

+--service2Submodule

Say I wanted to create a new feature for service 1. I could make a feature branch in service 1. Then I could make a feature branch for the main project. If integration tests pass, I could make a pull request to merge the feature branch of the parent directory into master. This all works fine - but the only issue is that then the master branch of the parent directory is pointing to a commit hash in the feature branch of the submodule. So one option would be to merge the feature branch of the submodule into the master branch first, then use the master branch of the submodule for the parent directory pull request. There are a lot of different options of how to to do this and they all basically accomplish the same thing, but none of them seam too ideal. I'm wondering if anyone has a tried and tested workflow that they could share? Thanks a lot.